# Can I run Cirq on IBMQ?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, cirq

Google's quantum computer is not yet available for the public. Is it possible to run Cirq on IBM's quantum computers, instead of Qiskit? And if so, how can I do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task can be accomplished via [cirq.QasmOutput](https://cirq.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/cirq.QasmOutput.html). I've attached an example of how to use the aforementioned functionality to run Cirq circuits on Qiskit's backends.

```
import cirq 
from typing import Tuple
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, execute, Aer

def main():
    q0 = cirq.LineQubit(1)  
    cirq_circuit = cirq.Circuit(
        cirq.H(q0),  
        cirq.measure(q0)
    )
    results, qasm_circuit = run_cirq_circuit_on_qiskit(cirq_circuit, (q0,), 'qasm_simulator')
    
    # Returns counts
    counts = results.get_counts(qasm_circuit)
    print("Total count for 00 and 11 are:", counts)
    
def run_cirq_circuit_on_qiskit(circuit: 'cirq.Circuit', qubits: Tuple['cirq.Qid', ...], backend: str):
    qasm_output = cirq.QasmOutput((circuit.all_operations()), qubits)
    qasm_circuit = QuantumCircuit().from_qasm_str(str(qasm_output))
    # Execute the circuit qiskit backend
    job = execute(qasm_circuit, Aer.get_backend(backend), shots=1000)
    # Grab results from the job
    return job.result(), qasm_circuit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

Good question. I tried to figure this out as well since I saw your question without much success.

However, I just wanted to point out that you can use Pennylane since it offers many external plugins so it allows you to run on many external hardware. See here: https://pennylane.ai/plugins.html

You can use Qiskit and aim at multiple external devices outside of IBM's QC. For instance, you can use Qiskit and run your code on Honeywell Trapped-ion backend given that you have an API token. See here: https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-honeywell-provider
There are a few other external backends that you can use through Qiskit.

So even though I wasn't able to find the solution to your question, I hope this helps.